# Proper Association Design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a need to do one query on a record set and get list of many type objects.

In this example I will use a blog post which a blog post has many different types.

**Base Post:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :postable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :body, :title
end
```

**Audio Post:**

```
class AudioPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sound
  has_one :postable, :as => :postable
end
```

**Graphic Post:**

```
class GraphicPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image
  has_one :postable, :as => :postable
end
```

This will allow me to do something like this.

```
@post = Post.all
@post.each do |post|
  post.title
  post.body
  post.postable.image if post.postable_type == "GraphicPost"
  post.postable.sound if post.postable_type == "AudioPost" 
end
```

Though this works, it feels wrong to check the type because that goes against the duck type principle. I would assume there is a better way then this to do the same thing.

What is be a better design to achieve this same goal or am I just over thinking my design?

Comment: Inheritance fits more for me in this case, why did you select polymorphic association?

Comment: I suppose you know STI, `AudioPost < Post`

Comment: Welcome to Rails city limits. If you go much further you may find yourself humming the tunes of Mr. Sinatra.

Comment: I did not want to use sti because of the many fields that would only pertain to the different types would end up polluting the table. Polymorphic feels more dry in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

See my comments.

Anyway, if you want polymorphic, I would write logic in model:

```
class Post
  delegate :content, to: :postable


class AudioPost
  alias_method :sound, :content


class GraphicPost
  alias_method :image, :content
```

You will want to render images different than a sound, for that part, I would use a helper:

```
module MediaHelper
  def medium(data)
    case # make your case detecting data type
    # you could print data.class to see if you can discriminate with that.
```

and call in view

```
= medium post.content
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, though I was not 100% sold on if I should be using polymorphic to achieve this. Mostly cause of what your showing. What you show is more duck typed, its also less transparent You end up using a condition in the end to render correctly. I'm not ruling you out, just want to see what other options are available.

You would probably agree that thought this maybe the best for polymorphic it maybe not the best over all design choice.